# Не могу подключиться к удаленной базе данных Workbench C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mysql-workbench

Не могу подключиться к удаленному серверу с бд worbench в WPF приложении. Думаю проблема в строке запроса, пытался искать какую нужно писать для wb, но так ничего толком и не нашел кроме советов "поищи в интернете". Прошу вас помочь с моей проблемой. Что не так в моем коде и как его можно починить?

Вот код:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;

    internal class DataBase
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection($"server = cfif31.ru; user=pavel;database=name;password=password;");

        public void openConnetction()
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
        }

        public void CloseConnetction()
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Подключение не удалось. Возможно у вас не включена база данных.");
            }
        }

        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            return sqlConnection;
        }
    }
```

Возникает ошибка "не получается подключиться к бд".

Comment: Вы используете `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` - класс для работы с Sql Server. А в метках у вас `mysql`.

Comment: в каких метах ?

Comment: метках, тегах, под вопросом, который вы ими пометили mysql-workbench, это не MSSQL. Какой именно типа базы данных?

Comment: все так, проблема была в том что я использовал не ту библиотеку